# How to invoke user defined non-static Java method from Ballerina

Tags: interop, ballerina, ballerina-java-interop

The example[1] shows how to invoke a Java method. But in my case I need to invoke my own method from my own class. Something like this

Hello.java

```
public class Hello {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello . . .";
    }
}
```

hello_java.bal

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/java;

function sayHelloJava() returns handle = @java:Method {
    name: "sayHello",
    class: "Hello"
} external;


public function main() {
    var txt = sayHelloJava();
    io:println(txt);
}
```

When I run, I am getting the following exception

```
Compiling source
        hello_java.bal
error: .::hello_java.bal:4:1: {ballerina/java}CLASS_NOT_FOUND 'Hello'
Running executables

Error: Could not find or load main class ___init
```

both the `.class` and the `.bal` files are in the same directory

can anyone please tell me the correct syntax to invoke the sayHello java method in ballerina.

Also could you explain more about the `handle` keyword in ballerina

[1] https://ballerina.io/v1-2/learn/by-example/invoke-java-methods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the [interop guide](https://ballerina.io/v1-2/learn/how-to-use-java-interoperability/) for a detailed info regarding this.

For your particular case, follow the following steps:

- Create a Java project for your `Hello` class and get the built `.jar` file.
- Create a new Ballerina project as well and add a module in it (let's say the module is called `hello`).
- Create a directory named `javalibs` in your project root directory and copy the `.jar` file to it.
- Your project directory look similar to the following:

  ```
  .
  ├── Ballerina.lock
  ├── Ballerina.toml
  ├── javalibs
  │   └── hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  └── src
      └── hello
          └── main.bal
  ```
- Add the following entries to your `Ballerina.toml` file:

  ```
  [platform]
  target = "java8"

     [[platform.libraries]]
     path = "./javalibs/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
     modules = ["hello"]
  ```
- Your Ballerina code should look something like the following:

  ```
  import ballerina/io;
  import ballerina/java;

  public type Hello object {
      public function sayHello() returns string? {
          return java:toString(sayHelloExtern());
      }
  };

  function sayHelloExtern() returns handle = @java:Method {
      class: "xyz.pubudu.Hello",
      name: "sayHello",
      paramTypes: []
  } external;


  public function main() {
      Hello h = new;
      io:println(h.sayHello());

      string? s = java:toString(sayHelloExtern());
      io:println(s);
  }
  ```
- Now you can run this using `ballerina run hello` and it should print `Hello . . .`

With the `1.2.0` release, a new CLI tool called `bindgen` was introduced to easily generate the Ballerina bindings for Java APIs so the user doesn't have to manually write the bindings as we've done above. Checkout the interop guide I linked to above for more details on it.

Comment: Thank you Pubudu, I am able to do it as mentioned in the interoperability guide. Unfortunately the exact ballerina code you mention didn't work for me (I tried this manually in a different project without bindgen). Anyway thanks again for the sample

Comment: Great! Glad you got it to work. With which version did you try? I tried this with 1.2.1 since I had some trouble with 1.2.0

Comment: I am using jBallerina 1.2.1 / Language specification 2020R1 / Ballerina tool 0.8.5
kindly see my gist for the error I am getting 
https://gist.github.com/bsenduran/5cceba9999a0d950621d6e5fa3615559

Comment: In your gist, you are trying to call a non-static method through ballerina. To call a non-static method, you first need to create an Object from you `Hello` class (You can use `java:Constructor` annotation in `ballerina/java` for that), and pass that into your `sayHelloExtern()` function.
[Refer this](https://ballerina.io/v1-2/learn/by-example/create-java-objects.html) for more info

Comment: @ThisaruG, Thank you. I have updated my gist. But unfortunately I am still getting an error (please see my gist for updated ballerina function and the error https://gist.github.com/bsenduran/5cceba9999a0d950621d6e5fa3615559). 
I was able to do this with `bindgen` I am trying this manually. kindly have a look at my code and correct me what I am missing

Comment: You have to pass the created instance to the `sayHello` function. To invoke non-static java methods using ballerina, you need to pass the `handle` of the instance of that Java class as the first parameter of the ballerina external function.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @pubudu's answer, I just want to show how to invoke a non-static Java method in Ballerina.

Since your `sayHello` method is a non-static method, you need to create an instance of the `Hello` class using `java:Constructor` annotation in ballerina.

Then your `sayHello` function should take that created instance (the `handle` value returned from the `java:Constructor` interop function) as the first parameter.

Your Ballerina code should look like this:

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/java;

function newHello() returns handle = @java:Constructor {
    class: "Hello"
} external;

function sayHello(handle helloObject) returns handle = @java:Method {
    class: "Hello"
} external;

public function main() {
    var helloObj = newHello();
    io:println(java:toString(sayHello(helloObj)));
}
```

Comment: instead of helloObj.sayHello(), we need to pass the Object right. Got it. thanks. it works